# Absolute referencing - Inserting the equivalent of '$' in an equation written in R1C1 notation

Tags: excel, vba

I have this equation that I am using VBA to enter into a cell on my spreadsheet:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],RC[-1]:R[" & CellNumber & "]C[-1],1,0)"
```

How do I have it enter the formula with `$` signs to keep the cell references locked?

I tried adding `$`s in their respective positions in the formula but that didn't work.

Comment: The whole `A1` versus `$A$1` referencing scheme is asinine, IMHO. I far prefer to use `R1C1` or `RC` mode. It is far clearer what is going on and you don't need to know where you are to know where the cell is that you're referencing. If it's `R[-1]C[1]` it's one cell up and one cell right. If you have `R10C3` then you know exactly where it is. Simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If not yet maybe one day you may notice the difference is that absolute references (i) do not use square brackets and (ii) always have a number immediately to the right of `R` and `C`, eg R1C1, which means Row 1, Column1 – usually expressed `A1` (though sometimes `R1C1` in the spreadsheet itself, as well as in a macro - when in what is termed R1C1 reference style).

`RC[-3]` is a relative reference and means whatever row happens to be the current one (no value immediately to the right of `R`, so no offset from the current row) and three columns to the left (because negative) of whatever happens to be the current column.

So if in `D1`, `RC[-3]` references exactly the same location as `R1C1` does – ie what is generally known as `A1`.

However because a relative reference, put `RC[-3]` in `E1` and it will reference `B1`, whereas `R1C1` (as does $A$1) refers to `A1` wherever it is placed.

Now, your example mentions `Active Cell` - that is where you formula will be placed and is the start point for "in the same row but three columns to the left". But you have not shown how the active cell was selected so we can't tell which cell to start from, therefore the location (rather than the direction/distance away) where you want to end up.

If on a chessboard for example, relative references might be "move your knight two rows up and one column to the right" whereas absolute would be "put your knight in square King 4".

In a sense, both 'systems' are relative – just that the "absolute" one is always relative to the top left-hand corner (except when using RTL layout).

It might help to think of the square brackets together `[ ]` as "from the cell I am in".

The equivalent of 'negative columns means to the left' for rows is 'up'.

Comment: Very helpful. It was the square brackets that were throwing me off. Great explanation. Muchos Gracias.

Comment: Yea, I get the relative positioning. The issue is that my brain doesn't think that way XD It's much easier for me to process `cells(r+1,1)`. I need a concrete variable that I can perform simple arithmetic on XD

Comment: @pnuts pffft the world should revolve around how my brain thinks.