# Unwanted parentheses are automatically inserted when writing formula to cell

Tags: excel, vba, formula, brackets

I'm trying to set a formula for a cell in Excel but I have a strange problem. With the line:

```
Range("BG4").Formula = "=CustomSum(BG:BG)"
```

it works fine and the correct formula is set into the cell. But I have another line of code:

```
Range("BH4").Formula = 
"=if(R1C1<>"""","""",if(CustomSum(BH:BH)=0,""geplant!"",CustomSum(BH:BH)))"
```

This line produces a formula in the cell which looks like this:

```
=IF($A$1<>"";"";IF(CustomSum(BH:(BH))=0;"geplant!";CustomSum(BH:(BH))))
```

which is unacceptable since it doesn't work (parentheses in parameter are inserted automatically).

How do I avoid that?

---

CustomSum looks as follows:

```
Public Function CustomSum(rng As Range)
    Dim Sum As Double
    Sum = 0
    For row = 10 To 48 Step 2
        If IsNumeric(Cells(row, rng.Column).Value) Then
            Sum = Sum + Cells(row, rng.Column).Value
        End If
    Next
    CustomSum = Sum
End Function
```

Comment: `"=if(R1C1<>"""","""",if(CustomSum(BH:BH)` - you can't mix `R1C1` and normal formulas

Comment: ok, i changed the function call to `CustomSum(C[60]:C[60])` that solved the problem! ty very much @simoco

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an answer, copied from a Comment by @simoco:

> `"=if(R1C1<>"""","""",if(CustomSum(BH:BH)`
>
> ... you can't mix R1C1 and normal formulas

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and found a response here: [Absolute referencing - Inserting the equivalent of '$' in an equation written in R1C1 notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21769812/absolute-referencing-inserting-the-equivalent-of-in-an-equation-written-in).

Long story short, since you have R1C1 at the beginning of your formula, the BH:BH needs to be in R1C1 coordinates as well.  BH is column 60. I'm not sure how to specify a whole column as you would in BH:BH, but if your total rows will always be under some large number (500? 6000? depending on your data), you could specify a large range and hopefully have it work fine.

If you have a title for your column, and your data starts row 2, I would write it like this:

```
Range("BH4").Formula = 
"=if(R1C1<>"""","""",if(CustomSum(R2C60:R6000C60)=0,""geplant!"",CustomSum(R2C60:R6000C60)))"
```